# Singular foliation of a particular singular distribution

Tags: differential-geometry, foliations

Let's consider the manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the singular distribution $D$ given by
$$ D_{(x,y)}=\left\langle\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\varphi(y)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right\rangle, \ \ \ \varphi(y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}0&\text{if}&y\leq0,\\ e^{-1/y^2}&\text{if}&y>0.\end{matrix}\right. $$
I know that $D$ is integrable, so, what is the corresponding singular foliation of this distribution? I know that for $y\leq0$ each horizontal line is a leaf, but I am not clear how the foliation is for $y>0$.

**Edit**: in fact, this is an example due to Sussman that can be found in somewhat more detail in the reference dealing with the problem of integrability of singular distributions.

Comment: For $y>0$, $D_{(x,y)}$ is all of $T_{(x,y)}\Bbb R^2 = \Bbb R^2$ right? The corresponding maximal leaf would be $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R_+^*$ I guess

Comment: @Didier, what do you mean by $\mathbb{R}_+^*$?

Comment: It is the standard notation in French for $\{ t \in \Bbb R \mid t > 0\}$. $\Bbb R^*$ is $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ and $\Bbb R_+$ is $\{t \mid t\geqslant 0\}$, and you just combine the two of them

Comment: Oh, I see. Then, that's the solution I'm looking for, but I don't know how to justify it.

Comment: Well, it's an immersed submanifold everywhere tangent to the distrubution. You just need to show that it is maximal

Comment: Oh, right, right. I think I see it now. I was foolishly confused.